# In groovy gsp Date format not working

Tags: jquery, date, grails, gsp

--Below code was working fine to populate the date format as specified. But dont know hte reason now it is not populating date value there, even though value exist in database.
I have tested by print statement before that then it is having the value.

```
<hsi:calendar name="orderDate_${line.id}" value="${order.orderDate?.format('yyyy-MM-dd')}" size="10" maxlength="10" />
```

-===What could be the reason, recently updated project with jquery new version. But if I use it as below then it is working.

```
<hsi:calendar name="orderDate_${line.id}" value="${order.orderDate}" size="10" maxlength="10" />
```

Comment: Just a guess but what is the expected "type" for the value param? I would expect a `calendar` object to require a `Date` object as input, which is what the second line appears to provide. In the first line it looks like you're providing a formatted (String). You might want to look at the `hsi:calendar` params to see if there is a format param to change the output format instead.

Comment: As nickdos said, the value attribut might expect a Date. I think you should check if there is another attribut for formatting that you can add to <calendar> tag.

Comment: <hsi:calendar name="orderDate_${line.id}" value="${orderDate}" format="MM/dd/yyyy" size="10" maxlength="10" /> worked fine to populate date in a required format. but it has something to do with jquery also.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried g:formatDate?

```
<g:formatDate format="MM-dd-yyyy" date="${order.orderDate}" />
```